# Warning for const in typedef

Tags: c++, warnings, constants, typedef

When I was compiling a C++ program using icc 11, it gave this warning:

> warning #21: type qualifiers are meaningless in this declaration
>   typedef const direction_vector_ref_t direction_vector_cref_t;

It is saying `const` just meaningless. I am curious about this since if this `typedef` expands it will turn into `const array<double,3>&` and the `const` is definitely meaningful. Why it gave this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure? Try:

```
array<double, 3> a;
direction_vector_cref_t b = a;
b[0] = 1.0;
```

The issue here, is that when you use a typedef, it conceptually adds parentheses around the type, so you are conceptually using `const (array<double, 3>&)` as opposed to `(const array<double, 3>)&`, so you are not actually making the referent object constant. So your declaration is more like:

```
typedef array<double, 3>& const direction_vector_cref_t;
```

And in the above, the const for the variable (rather than the referent type) needs to be deferred till later.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is a priority problem. it is `const (type ref)` rather than `(const type) ref`

Answer (score 6):

direction_vector_ref_t, I pressume, its a reference. References are const by design, so adding const to a reference is meaningless. What you probably want is to make a reference to a const object, which can't be done by a typedef. You will have to repeat the slightly modified typedef definition.

Just to clarify:

```
typedef T& ref;
typedef const T& cref;
typedef const ref cref;
```

The last line is the same as the first one, not the second one. Typedefs are not token pasting, once you typedef T& as ref, then ref refers to the reference to T type. If you add const to it, then you get a const reference to T type, not a reference to a const T type.

Comment: Could you please give a little more details?

Comment: @nightcracker: Um...they definitely are.  Show me the code that lets you re-assign a reference.

Comment: @xis19: Still need more detail? Typedefs are not token pasting, once you typedef T& as ref, then ref refers to the reference to T type. If you add const to it, then you get a const reference to T type, not a reference to a const T type.

Comment: @K-ballo: So it looks like the trick discussed in char* string[] and char (*string)[]?

Comment: I'm not aware of it, sounds similar but not the same issue. As a general rule I tend to add const to the right, rather than to the left, to catch this kinds of things. Compare what you get in the typedef, between T const& to T& const and the problem becames obvious.

Comment: @K-ballo that's exactly what I wanted to know. +1